# using startAtOperationTime while fetching data with Cosmos for Mongo Change Streams

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to use the startAtOperationTime function while quering Cosmos for Mongo Change streams. I am using java for the same. Any attempt to use this is giving me error:-
java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.bson.BsonTimestamp

Can someone please help with the same.

I tried converting the current time to epoch time and use the same but that resulted into error.

I am using the the below code:
cursor = collection.watch(pipeline).fullDocument(FullDocument.UPDATE_LOOKUP).startAtOperationTime("1683631946").cursor();

Here 1683631946 - Epoch time

Comment: can you add some code?